# JUnit XML "packages" in hudson

Tags: junit, hudson, jenkins

I'm generating XML's myself that look enough like JUnit for Hudson to read them.  It works great except I can't figure out what the "packages" list is in the Hudson web GUI.  How do I make an XML that will be interpreted by Hudson as a "package?"

```
<testsuites>
<testsuite>

  <testcase classname="class\name\that\is\really\folders" name="test_name.log" time="231">
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Hudson will list this as:

Package:   (root)
Class:     class\name\that\is\really\folders
Test Name: test_name.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Jenkins takes the package name from the name attribute in the testsuite tag.
You could try changing your XML like this

```
<testsuites>
<testsuite name="package.name.of.your.testclass">

  <testcase classname="class\name\that\is\really\folders" name="test_name.log" time="231">
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Answer (score 6):

@pushy - I tried that before, but when I tried to prove you wrong I got it this time ;-).

```
<testsuites>
<testsuite name="package.name.of.your.testclass">

  <testcase classname="package.name.of.your.testclass.class\name\that\is\really\folders" name="test_name.log" time="231">
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

You **must** prefix the classname of each test case with the testsuite name for it to be accepted as a "package".

Answer (score 2):

No need for redundancy! Jenkins nicely infers the package and class names if you:

- use the `name` attribute instead of `classname`
- ensure the `<testsuite>` element's `name` attribute has at least two dot delimited "sections." Now all the enclosed `<testcase>` elements will get a package and class. The very last part will be the class name. The remainder will be be the package name.

Like this:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="packagename.classname">
      <testcase name="test_name.log" time="231"></testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Comment: This does not allow you to structure your modules into a hierarchy (which was my actual goal).